# kotling mutableMapOf<String, MutableSet<String>> error

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, collections, set, runtime

`val bucket = mutableMapOf<String, MutableSet<String>>()`

I insert multiple keys in bucket.
My logic is here

```
 for(temp in report_unique){
            val str = temp.split(" ")//str example = "a b"
            
            if(bucket.containsKey(str[0]))
                bucket[str[0]]?.add(str[1])
            else{
                val t = mutableSetOf<String>()
                bucket[str[0]]? = t // runtime error
                bucket[str[0]]?.add(str[1])
            }
```

I don`t know why the error occured, and want to know right answer.
So Hard Kotlin null checking.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? What error exactly do you have? Also, I believe you should have a compile error here, not a runtime error.

Comment: You should remove `?` when assigning values. `bucket[str[0]] = t`

Comment: @ocos my error like this

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
 at Solution.solution(Solution.kt:39)
 at SolutionRunnerKt$main$1.invoke(SolutionRunner.kt:48)
 at SolutionRunner.run(SolutionRunner.kt:28)
 at SolutionRunnerKt.main(SolutionRunner.kt:48)

Comment: It i delete the '?' , above error occured. I check the point where error occured. the line is the point

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: since you clarified in the comments with more information and your actual code doesn't use the problematic `?`, the problem is a bit clearer:

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

This error tells you that you're trying to access index 0 in `str`, and it's out of bounds because `str` is of length 0 (it has 0 elements). By accessing index 0, you're assuming that str contains at least 1 element, but it's apparently not the case.

You should look at what `temp` contains. If `temp == ""`, `split` will return an empty list, and you'll see this error.

---

##### Original answer

I think you're mistaken and you don't have a *runtime* error but a *compile* error. Trying [your code on the Kotlin playground](https://pl.kotl.in/DxIi3_AvQ), I got the following compile error:

> Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

This is because the syntax of `bucket[str[0]]? = t` is invalid, you have an extra `?`. Let's break it down.

The basic function to insert into a map is `put`, as in `map.put(key, value)`. On top of that, Kotlin provides a [convenient `set` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/operator-overloading.html#indexed-access-operator) that allows you to use the square bracket syntax. So when you write `map[key] = value`, it's translated into `map.set(key, value)`.

The syntax for this specific operator doesn't support any `?` here, and it's not even necessary in your case anyway, as you could simply write:

```kotlin
bucket[str[0]] = t
```

The map is not null, and here you're not trying to use a null value, you're assigning a non-null value to a key in the map, so there is no need to use any safe operator (`?`).

#### Alternative code

Now that this is out of the way, note that you can the whole `if` with the help of `computeIfAbsent`:

```kotlin
for(temp in report_unique){
    val str = temp.split(" ")//str example = "a b"

    bucket.computeIfAbsent(str[0]) { mutableSetOf<String>() }.add(str[1])
}
```

You could even replace the whole thing by creating the `bucket` map directly using `groupBy`:

```kotlin
val bucket = report_unique.groupBy({ it.substringBefore(" ") }, { it.substringAfter(" ")})
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but If i delete this `?`, Runtime error occured. ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0```

Comment: Then you have to investigate the problem that the error tells you about: you're trying to access index 0 in `str`, and it's out of bounds because `str` is of length 0 (it has 0 elements). By accessing index 0, you're assuming that `str` contains at least 1 element. You should look at what `temp` contains. If `temp == ""`, `split` will return an empty list.